# I can't install golang and godoc at the same time on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go

I installed golang using `sudo apt-get install golang`. Then I can use the `go` command. But there is no godoc command. I found online I can use `sudo apt-get install golang-go.tools` to install godoc. When I do that I can use the `godoc` command but the `go` command doesn't work anymore. How can I make them both work on the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my first suggestion is to try removing the `golang-go.tools` package, and try `go get golang.org/x/tools/godoc`; see if that works.

Beyond that, adding more details would help.  What error(s) are you getting when you try to run the `go` command now?

Comment: I installed godoc as you said. No errors. It shows up in /usr/lib/go/bin folder instead of my $GOPATH. Is that normal?

I can't execute the command godoc, but I can execute it from that folder correctly

Comment: If you mean you can run `/usr/lib/go/bin/godoc`, but you can't just type `godoc`, you probably just need to add that dir to your `$PATH`.  If you're using bash, ksh, or the like, that should just require `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/go/bin`.  Run that from the command line and see if it enables you to run `godoc`.  If so, add that line to your .bashrc (or equivalent) and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install `golang` by `apt-get`.

First uninstall golang

```
apt-get purge golang*
```

Download compiled go archive from https://golang.org/dl/

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv go /usr/local
```

You may need to set Go Paths. Then you can test your install.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
go version
```

`godoc` should be usable now.